# Why is loop not finding all the page breaks?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping up to 7000 rows and finding each page break and moving it up like 10 rows, when it's gets 3/4 down, it stops around 5500 and leaves around 5-8 page breaks not being moved?

Could it be that since moving them up it created additional page break not included in the original loop? If so, how would I fix that?

```
Dim i As Long
Dim pb As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
For Each pb In ws.HPageBreaks
    For i = pb.Location.Row To 1 Step -1
         If Cells(i,1) = 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Cells(i, 1)
         End If
    Next

Next
```

Comment: I suspect your suspicion about it adding more page breaks is correct. Can you loop backwards through the page breaks? (via index or something)?

Comment: I need to move the page breaks up from beginning at the top. I'm not sure how to find the additional page breaks that gets created at the bottom though.

Comment: could the fact that you are looping back to `1` each time be affecting it. Seems like going all the way back to row `1` each time is superflouos.

Comment: no, this is a shorten version of the real code but that 1 is so that i know where to put the page break only. I'm sure it is adding additional page break towards the bottom as i move it up. Not sure how to accommodate for those one's at the bottom.

Comment: is there a way to find page breaks within a range of rows?

Comment: this is a hack, but what if you loop through `pb` again and remove breaks that are `Cells(pb.Location.Row`,1) <> 1`?

Comment: in order to move anything from one place to another, you have to create the destination object and then delete to source object. your code does not delete anything.  i think that you are missing `pb.delete` after the `end if`